# Tents and trees constraints

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc

I am trying to express the constraints for the 'Tents and trees' puzzle in minizinc but I am a bit stuck...

1. I can express that each tent must be attached to at least one tree
2. That a tree must be attached to at least one tent
3. That no tent can touch another tent

However, I cannot express that 'each tent/tree must be attached to only one tree/tent' and get incorrect solutions generated such as 'tent-tree-tent'

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Assuming for you $x_i = 1$ is tent on index $i$, $0$ implies tree then constraint may be $x_i + x_{i+1} = 1$. Then you'd get $1,0,1$ or $0,1,0$

Comment: The answer will depend on how you write your CP model. If you edit the question to show the CP model, we may be able to provide a more definitive answer.